# Setting dataTextField value in Kendo UI kendoComboBox object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have a Kendo UI combobox object something like this :

```
widget: "kendoComboBox",
            options: {
                dataTextField: "#:userFirstName#&nbsp#:userLastName#",
                dataValueField: "userId",

                template: "#:userFirstName#&nbsp#:userLastName#",
                change: function (e) {
                    that.model.fn.bringUserData();
                }
            }
```

I can arrange the template, but i cannot dataTextField value depends on that template. It is possible to make it "userId" etc. But seems not possible to set selected value as #:userFirstName#&nbsp#:userLastName#. (dataTextFieldTemplate doesn't work.)

Could you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct, you cannot make it a composition of two fields. It needs to be a field *per se*. What you can do is when reading data from the DataSource create an additional field that is the concatenation of those two fields. You can add to you DataSource definition  something like this:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
              url: "..."
        }
    },
    schema: {
        parse: function(response) {
            $.each(response, function(idx, elem) {
                elem.fullName = elem.firstName + " " + elem.lastName;
            });
            return response;
        }
    }
});
```

Then the options for the combobox are simply:

```
options: {
    dataTextField: "fullName",
    dataValueField: "userId",
    ...
}
```

See it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/12hpLeux/1/